# Microsoft Team finding person deleting channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft365

Somewhere we have a user(s) that have deleted several channels on Microsoft teams.

We have a feeling it is someone that is trying to hide the channel and not delete it.
I would assume this would be logged in a security audit somewhere, I am just not sure where.

Is there a way to find who this is so we can educate them or disable their right to delete stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** The audit log can help you investigate specific activities across Microsoft 365 services. You can check deleted channel activity in audit log from Microsoft 365 compliance as below. Choose Date and time range and Deleted channel activity. Then, click Search button to retrieve the related event.
[image]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/audit-log-events

**2.** If you want to recover the deleted channels, follow below steps:

- Click More options next to the target team > choose Manage team
- Open Channels tab and expand the Deleted list > Click the Restore button.

[image]